# Multi Processing in python

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am trying to record Set top box signal using videorecording feature of opencv in python.
I am using capture device to capture the set top box signal whose FPS is 30.
Video Recording from External capture device is successful using opencv.

Here is the code for video recording

```
#VideoRecord.py
CaptureDeviceID = 1
cap = VideoCapture(CaptureDeviceID)
if cap.isOpened():
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
else:
    exit()

fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC()
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 30.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    frameNo = 0
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frameNo++
        # write the frame
        out.write(frame)
    
        if (frameNo > 150):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now through Script I am changing channel using IRBlaster command.
This channel change should come in recorded video.

## code for sending channel+ command

```
# sendCommand.py
redrat_path = r'C:\Program Files\RedRat\RedRat Control\RR_CLI_V3.01\RR_CLI.exe
redrat_process=subprocess.Popen(\"%s %s\" % (redrat_path,\"RedRat-0  -output RedRatDB.xml  -device STB1 -signal  Channel+ "))
```

In words I want to record video and  send command in parallel process.So that the created video file has this
channel change event recorded.

How should I achieve this effectively so that I will not miss any frame while I am sending channel change command?.
Do i have to use threading?

Please suggest some ideas.I want to use Python

Comment: `frameNo++` should be `frameNo+=1`. Just to send it to an other process has no effect. What is the goal you want to achieve? What do you want to pass to a function as arguments?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. what i want is command to be sent while video is being recorded. how to should i implement threading so that I will not miss any frame while command sending code is being executed.